# Value of $\frac1{\Vert f\Vert}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> For $V=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=1\}$ show that $\inf\{\Vert x\Vert\mid x\in V\}=\frac1{\Vert f\Vert}$, where $X$ is banach and $f$ is a nontrivial element of the dual space of $X$.

For $x\in V$ we have $$\vert f(x)\vert=1\leq\Vert f\Vert\Vert x\Vert\implies\Vert x\Vert\geq\frac1{\Vert f\Vert}.$$ So in particular $\inf\{\Vert x\Vert\mid x\in V\}\geq\frac1{\Vert f\Vert}$,.

However, I'm not able to show: $$\inf\{\Vert x\Vert\mid x\in V\}\leq\frac1{\Vert f\Vert}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from 
$$
\|f\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} |f(x)|.
$$
If you like, take a sequence $x_k$ such that $\|x_k\|=1$ and $|f(x_k)| \to \|f\|$.
Then set $y_k = x_k / |f(x_k)|$, so $|f(y_k)| = 1$, and $\|y_k\| \to \frac{1}{\|f\|}$.

Comment: This is a direct proof, right? I don't need the inequalities, do I?

Comment: This, establishes the lower bound you're looking for, but you still need the first half of your argument.  (To make sure that you can't cook up a better sequence $y_k$).